# SharePoint PnP Modern search not working with refinable string for hub site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search, managed-property, hub-site, pnp-search-webparts

I have sharepoint online hub site and around 100 sites associated to hub site. I am using PnP modern search, I want search to work on `refinablestring`, it is mapped to document type which is content type choice column, Document library is created from same content type for all sites.

The problem is search do not search items from the associated sites when query template contains refinable string. I have below query

```
{searchTerms} RefinableString05: Bulk Data
Path:"https://dummy.sharepoint.com/sites/myHub"
```

I expect this to return the results from the hub site and all associated sites where my `refinablestring` is `Bulk Data`

Currently it return the results only from hub site not the associated sites, the query searches for all sites if I remove the `refinablestring`

```
{searchTerms} 
Path:"https://dummy.sharepoint.com/sites/myHub
```

Can someone please help me on this, I am stuck on this for couple of days.